# Undefined method ArraySubsetLegacy::exporter() when executing php vendor/bin/simple-phpunit

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, simple-phpunit

I'm discovering API Platform and i'm now at the "Testing the API" step.

I get two different errors I can't resolve, event avec a composer install / update :

```
1) App\Tests\BooksTest::testGetCollection
Error: Call to undefined method ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Constraint\ArraySubsetLegacy::exporter()

/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Constraint/ArraySubsetTrait.php:76
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Constraint/ArraySubsetTrait.php:84
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Constraint/ArraySubsetTrait.php:68
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Constraint/ArraySubsetLegacy.php:32
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/ApiTestAssertionsTrait.php:100
/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/ApiTestAssertionsTrait.php:57
/srv/api/tests/BooksTest.php:26
```

and

```
4) App\Tests\BooksTest::testUpdateBook
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client::request() must be of the type string, null given, called in /srv/api/tests/BooksTest.php on line 103

/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php:88
/srv/api/tests/BooksTest.php:103
```

Any idea ?

Thx :-)

Comment: Can you show your BooksTest please? The tests with the lines from the stack trace (26 and 103) should be enough, if the file is too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [this issue on API Platform](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3153) the API Platform framework uses phpUnit 7.5 by default, but some of the test functions use phpUnit 8.

you can supposedly set SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION to 8.3 as an environment variable, but that didn't work in my case. I had to edit api/phpunit.xml.dist and change the value in there to look like this:

```
<server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="8.3" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked !  I tried to set it to 9 and it worked well too  I don't know why they didn't fix this in their release though 

Comment: from what i gleaned from the issue on github, it is a backwards compatibility issue.